# (ANDROID)Store location name into firebase together with longtitude&latitude and retrieve location name from firebase

Tags: java, android

```
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }


    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }


    DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.child("Location");

    myRef.push().setValue(mLastLocation);
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Oops " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}
```

How to store location name into firebase since I only successfully store longtitude&latitude. And how to retrieve the data with location name from the firebase into listview? I am currently new in Android.Please help.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please post your code and point out where the issues are, and also review [Ask].

Comment: Hello, anyone here would like to lend a hand?